# Passing props from a navlink to a component React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to pass a props from my navlink to another component, but, when I make the call from the console, I get an error

Nav Link

```
<NavLink price={price} className="NavProjet" to={{
   pathname:"/boutique/checkout/",
   state: {
      price: {price},
     
    } }} >
```

Component Page

```
console.log("price",props.location.state.price)
```

Console error => Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

If someone have a solution? Thanks for time!

Answer (score 0):

You're giving an object as a value to the state, for example:

```
price: {
  price: {
    prix: 'hello',
  }
}
```

So you would access it, as of right now, by `console.log("price",props.location.state.price.prix)`.
I think you meant to do:

```
state: price
```

?. This would make it possible to do `props.location.state.prix`.

Comment: Hi, what I want is the value "price" sorry just edited my question

Comment: Try `to{{ pathname: '..', state: price }}`. Now `price` _is_ `props.location.state`.

Comment: Same error Cannot read property 'state' of undefined, i have to declare state?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED !

```
<NavLink prix={prix} className="NavProjet" to={{
   pathname:"/boutique/checkout/",
   state: {
      prix: `${prix}`,
     
    } }} >
```

And Component page

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

 const location = useLocation();
  
  console.log(location.state.prix);
```

Comment: If your 'Component page' is the routed componented from the `'/boutique/checkout/'` path, you'll already receive the location in the props of your component, so you won't have to use `useLocation()`. You would access the location via `props.location`.